# Multi-group rankings using data table package

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data frame containing a group identifier and a score for an observation from that group for an activity. Both group letters and scores can repeat.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

set.seed(1)

dat <- data.frame(rowid = 1:1000, 
                  grp = sample(LETTERS[1:20], 1000, replace = T),
                  score = sample(1:5, 1000, replace = T))
```

For each group, I need to rank their distinct scores in descending order; for each unique group and score combination, I would like to retain a single row. Ideally, this row would be the row with the smallest rowid, but this is not absolutely necessary. If it is more efficient to randomly select a row from each group and score combination, that works just as well.

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  mutate(score_rank = dense_rank(desc(score))) %>% 
  arrange(grp, score_rank, rowid) %>% ## this step not completely necessary (see above)
  group_by(grp, score_rank) %>% 
  mutate(score_rank_row = row_number()) %>% 
  filter(score_rank_row == 1) %>% 
  arrange(grp, -score)
```

The code above accomplishes what I want to do, but in reality, my actual data frame has 20m+ rows, has 5,000 values for group, and each group can have hundreds of scores, many of which repeat. As a result, when I try to use the solution presented above for my actual use case, my computer keeps running and running without finishing the operation.

My understanding is that `data.table` is much more efficient at handling these types of tasks, but I cannot for the life of me figure out the syntax to use it. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `data.table`, we can use

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, score_rank := frank(-score, ties.method =  'dense'), grp]
setkey(dat, grp, score_rank, rowid)
dat[, score_rank_row := rowid(grp, score_rank)][
           score_rank_row == 1][order(grp, -score)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option:

```
setorder(unique(dat, by=c("grp","score")), grp, -score, rowid)[, 
    c("score_rank","score_rank_row") := .(rowid(grp), 1L)]
```

And if you want the row to be the row with the smallest rowid, you can order first before filtering:

```
setorder(dat, grp, -score, rowid)
unique(dat, by=c("grp","score"))[, c("score_rank","score_rank_row") := .(rowid(grp), 1L)]
```